# Integrate $\cos x^5$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to solve this, but i can't get it right.

$$\int \cos\ x^5\ dx$$

$$u=x^5\\
\frac{du}{dx}=5x^4 \Rightarrow du=5x^4 dx, dx=\frac{1}{5x^4}du\\
\int \cos x^5 dx \Rightarrow \int \cos(u)\frac{1}{5x^4}du\Rightarrow \frac{1}{5x^4}\sin(u) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{5x^4}\sin(x)^5 $$

A side question: Is $\cos\ x^5$ equal to $\cos^5\ x$?

Comment: $cos(x^5)$ needs to be expanded using Maclurian series of cos(x). And $\cos^5x\neq \cos (x^5)$, without the expansions, the answer is $$\dfrac{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{1}{5},-\mathrm{i}x^5\right)-\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{1}{5},\mathrm{i}x^5\right)}{10\sqrt[10]{-1}} + C$$

Comment: Notice that 
$$u = x^5 \Rightarrow x = u^{\frac{1}{5}} \Rightarrow dx = \frac{1}{5}u^{-\frac{4}{5}}du,$$ and hence 
$$\int \cos x^5 dx = \int (\cos u) \frac{1}{5}u^{-\frac{4}{5}}du.$$ 
Anyway, even with the substitution, this integral is rather hard to be solved using standard functions.